# What are 'Regular Products'?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, roots, functional-equations, riemann-zeta

When looking at the functional equation for the Riemann zeta function, I came across the statement:

> For $s$ an even positive integer, the product $\sin{(\frac{\pi s}{2})}\Gamma({1-s})$ is regular.

How come this does not evaluate to zero at positive even values of $s$, due to the sine function, or remain undefined due to the poles in the Gamma function? Is it to do with the series expansions by any chance?

Comment: It means that the simple poles of Gamma function are deleted from the zeros of sine.

Comment: So what number does this expression evaluate to? Is it 1, 0 or some function of $s$? And if so, why does this occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that the functional equation of the Riemann zeta function $$\zeta\left(s\right)=2^{s}\pi^{s-1}\sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(1-s\right)\zeta\left(1-s\right)
 $$ holds on the whole complex plane except for $s=1
 $. In particular, it is possible to calculate your product at $s=2n
 $, with $n=1,2,\dots
 $. We have $$\sin\left(n\pi\right)\Gamma\left(1-2n\right)=\frac{\zeta\left(2n\right)}{2^{s}\pi^{s-1}\zeta\left(1-2n\right)}
 $$ (we are sure that $\zeta\left(1-2n\right)\neq0
 $ because $1-2n$ is a negative odd integer) and we have closed form for zeta in these particular cases $$\zeta\left(2n\right)=\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\frac{B_{2n}\left(2\pi\right)^{2n}}{2\left(2n\right)!}
 $$ and $$\zeta\left(1-2n\right)=\zeta\left(-\left(2n-1\right)\right)=-\frac{B_{2n}}{2n}$$ where $B_{n}
 $ are Bernoulli numbers. So $$\sin\left(n\pi\right)\Gamma\left(1-2n\right)=\left(-1\right)^{n}\frac{\pi}{2\left(2n-1\right)!}.
 $$

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you very much for taking the time to explain it.